# Checked event command binding on RadioButton doesn't work when the control is dynamically created

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have 3 `RadioButton` controls that I add to my `WPF` program dynamically, with the help of a custom class I've defined and an `ItemsControl`. My custom class is simple; it has two properties, one an identifier and the other a `bool` to represent the `Checked/Unchecked` status.

```
public class RadioButtonItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using `MVVMLight`, and a `ViewModel`, and `DataContext` etc are all properly setup.

In the `MainWindow` I have the `RadioButton` controls added like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RadioButtons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding ItemName}" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                             Margin="12" GroupName="ABC">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RadioButtonCheckedCommand}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Note that `i` is the `Interactivity` namespace:
    `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Now in my `ViewModel`, I create a list of `RadioButtonItem` instances, and at loading time it creates 3 `RadioButton` controls in the `XAML` end just fine, as I expect it to. Then using `MVVMLight` command `RelayCommand`, I hook up the `Checked` event to the `RadioButtonCheckedCommand` command, which in turn is supposed to call the `RadioButtonChecked()` private method.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<RadioButtonItem> _radioButtons;
    public List<RadioButtonItem> RadioButtons
    {
        get => _radioButtons;
        set { _radioButtons = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public RelayCommand RadioButtonCheckedCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        RadioButtons = new List<RadioButtonItem>
        {
            new RadioButtonItem() { ItemName = "A", IsChecked = false },
            new RadioButtonItem() { ItemName = "B", IsChecked = false },
            new RadioButtonItem() { ItemName = "C", IsChecked = false },
        };

        RadioButtonCheckedCommand = new RelayCommand(RadioButtonChecked);
    }

    private void RadioButtonChecked()
    {

    }
}
```

But, when I run the program it doesn't call the said event. Neither does it give me any errors. How do I get an event to work in a dynamically created control like this?

To verify my command bindings etc. work, I also created three static `RadioButton` controls on my window, as shown below, and attached them to the same command and they work fine on `Checked` event.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <RadioButton Content="X" Margin="12">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RadioButtonCheckedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Content="Y" Margin="12">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RadioButtonCheckedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Content="Z" Margin="12">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RadioButtonCheckedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `ItemsControl`, binding to RadioButtonCheckedCommand is trying to resolve it against an item - `RadioButtonItem` instance

but the command is defined in MainViewModel. it works in the StackPanel because there are no bindings to RadioButtonItems.

the solution is to bind to ItemsControl.DataContext (same as Grid.DataContext):

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RadioButtonCheckedCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer is perfect. Just another solution if you don't want to use elemnt name "LayoutRoot".

`<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RadioButtonCheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>`